# Send email to user notifying them that something new was posted on their profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3 app, a person's profile can have superlatives. In fact, the `Profile` model is set up so it `:has_many :superlatives` and `Superlative` `:belongs_to :profile`. What I'd like to do is send my Users an email when their profile receives a new superlative. I'm just not sure what to pass into my Mailer and Mailer action to make this work. Can someone help me out?

I've been following the RailsCast on [Action Mailer](http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3) to send other emails, so all of my mailer stuff is in the controller. I don't understand a lot of what's going on. I know I need to use the newly created superlative to find the Profile to find the User to find the User's email (which makes me think there is an easier way to do this. I tried assigning `@profile` in the `Superlatives#create` action but that was throwing an error.

That being said, I've tried quite a bit and have posted my code below.

My `create` action in my superlatives_controller:

```
def create
  @superlative = Superlative.new(params[:superlative].merge(:author_id => current_user.id))
  if @superlative.save!
    SuperlativeMailer.new_superlative(@user).deliver
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { }
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'fail_superlative_create.js.erb' }
    end
  end
end
```

And my SuperlativeMailer's `new_superlative` action:

```
def new_superlative(user)
  @superlative = superlative
  @profile = superlative.profile
  @user = superlative.profile.user
  mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "#{@superlative.name} just gave you a superlative.")
end
```

However with all of this I receive an error:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `superlative' for #<SuperlativeMailer:0x103c006a8>):
  app/mailers/superlative_mailer.rb:6:in `new_superlative'
  app/controllers/superlatives_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `Superlative` object to the mailer instead of the `User`

```
def new_superlative(superlative)
  @superlative = superlative
  @profile = superlative.profile
  @user = superlative.profile.user
  mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => "#{@superlative.name} just gave you a superlative.")
end
```

And in the controller

`SuperlativeMailer.new_superlative(@superlative).deliver`